# got problem when replace github.com/apache/rocketmq-clients/golang to my github fork in go.mod

Tags: go, github, go-modules

i use this in my go.mod:

`require github.com/apache/rocketmq-clients/golang v0.0.0-20230321063829-41bfbcf6130d`

and i want to replace it to my fork: github.com/ainokiseki/rocketmq-clients/golang

first i try:

`replace github.com/apache/rocketmq-clients/golang => github.com/ainokiseki/rocketmq-clients/golang master`

but i get:

`replace github.com/ainokiseki/rocketmq-clients/golang: version "v0.0.0-20230925081057-23da93ce6e7d" invalid: golang/go.mod has post-v0 module path "github.com/apache/rocketmq-clients/golang/v5" at revision 23da93ce6e7d`

then i try:

`replace github.com/apache/rocketmq-clients/golang/v5 => github.com/ainokiseki/rocketmq-clients/golang master`

and i get:

`replace github.com/ainokiseki/rocketmq-clients/golang: version "v0.0.0-20230925081057-23da93ce6e7d" invalid: golang/go.mod has post-v0 module path "github.com/apache/rocketmq-clients/golang/v5" at revision 23da93ce6e7d`

finally i try:

`replace github.com/apache/rocketmq-clients/golang/v5 => github.com/ainokiseki/rocketmq-clients/golang/v5 master`

this time running `go mod tidy` did not meet any error, but it doesn't work, still the apache repo, not my repo. my go.mod looks like:
`replace github.com/apache/rocketmq-clients/golang/v5 => github.com/ainokiseki/rocketmq-clients/golang/v5 v5.0.0-20230925074920-efc3d0c4979c`

UPDATE: How did i know it failed: i tried to call a function added in the master branch of my repo, but it failed.

So how should i do?

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work ? `go mod edit replace` will not actually replace the former with the latter in the `go.mod`. It will just add a line at the end saying `replace <older_module> => <new_module>`. So now when you use the older_module in the code, it will use the new_module behind the scenes. Could you please add the `go.mod` file after running the command in your question ?